# I have an account at the BBT and money was seized for inactivity

Tags: united-states, banking, bank-account

Hi I had an account at the Wachovia that then became the Colonial and now its de BBT. I have not used the account for years but checked online regularly. I now go to the bank and they told me the money was seized by the treasure hunt or something like that. How can I get my money back. Should I hire a lawyer ?

Comment: "seized by the treasure hunt or something like that" - If you didn't understand what the bank was telling you, you need to go back to the bank and ask them to explain.

Answer (score 7):

In general if there are no transactions for several years a bank will close the account. In my experience they also send at least one warning notice.

If they do close the account they send it to the state. Each state has an unclaimed property office. You can contact them regarding the procedure to get the money. If this money was just turned over to the state there may be some lag time before you can get it back.

Two notes:

- the state government doesn't charge a fee to get your money back. Don't pay a company a finder's fee.
- bank account's owned by minors don't have the same activity requirements as those owned by adults.